# How to use hl7 encoding transformer connector in mule?

Tags: encoding, mule, hl7, transformer-model

As I am new to mule anypointstudio, can anyone help in the usage of hl7 encoding transformer connector. I have created the application for this by using hl7 encoding transformer but it is just transferring the file from one directory to another without transforming it to XML.
The Flow I have made is as follows:

FILE - logger - hl7 encoding transformer connector - logger - file

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the MuleSoft documentation? Can see some examples there:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/healthcare-toolkit/v/3.0/hl7-edi#hl7-and-mllp-dataweave-example

https://docs.mulesoft.com/healthcare-toolkit/v/3.0/hl7-edi#use-hl7-edi-inside-mule-flows

Comment: Thanks for the useful tutorial, but under available software I am not getting any option of " MULE hl7 Transport "